# Active Directory Attribute changing value

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I am trying fetch the **whenChanged** attribute for a user record from Active Directory using the DirectorySearcher class.

It seems the value is changed during or maybe after it is fetched because it is not the same as the value I can see in LDAP.

E.g. For my own profile the value in LDAP reads: *11/29/2022 5:10:21 Eastern Standard Time* but after fetching this value through my code, it says *11/29/2022 10:10:24*. Please note it is not 10:10 as per my system clock.

The obvious conclusion is that it is a time zone issue. But my system is in EST too. Also the difference in time is different for different users.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: *The Active Directory stores date/time values as the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since the 0 hour on January 1, 1601 until the date/time that is being stored. **The time is always stored in Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) in the Active Directory.***

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things going on.

1. As mentioned by Selvin, the value is always stored in GMT, which explains the 5-hour difference.
2. The value is not replicated between domain controllers, which explains the 3-second difference.

To explain the second point in more detail, let's take an example where a user's `title` is updated. When that update happens, the `whenChanged` attribute is updated *on the DC where the change was made*. Then when the new `title` value is replicated to another DC, that other DC updates the `whenChanged` attribute *to the time when the replication happened*. Because of that, the `whenChanged` value will be different on each DC.

The `whenChanged` values will usually be pretty close, but they can differ significantly. For example, when you logon, the `lastLogon` attribute is updated on the DC you authenticated to, along with `whenChanged`. However, `lastLogon` is not replicated, so the `whenChanged` value on all the other DCs will not get updated. That is, unless it's time to update the [`lastLogonTimestamp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-lastlogontimestamp) value, in which case that will replicate.

So if you're checking the value, make sure you're reading from the same DC. With `DirectoryEntry`, you can specify the DC you want to use in the LDAP path:

```
var user = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://dc1.example.com/CN=someuser,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com"
               , null, null, AuthenticationTypes.ServerBind);
```

The use of `AuthenticationTypes.ServerBind` is because [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.authenticationtypes?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#:%7E:text=Specifying%20a%20server%20name%20without%20also%20specifying%20this%20flag%20results%20in%20unnecessary%20network%20traffic.) says:

> Specifying a server name without also specifying this flag results in unnecessary network traffic.

Or you can get the DC that `DirectoryEntry` automatically found by using:

```
var dc = user.Options.GetCurrentServerName();
```